# How can I conditionally cancel drop while hovering over a droppable?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a setup where I want to conditionally revert an element that is being dropped

(I tried using the `accept` event, but that proved to run far too often for practical purposes. - not only that, its use cancels other events.)

**EDIT: its actually not that it runs far too often, but rather that.. when it fires, `$(this).attr('id')` becomes incorrect upon revisiting hovered over elements. http://jsfiddle.net/UvByv/1/**

For example above:

1. grab a piece and hover over various squares.
2. note the square number it hovers over. it doesn't always update as it should.

You will see that the square elements are numbered.  When a square is revisited, `$(this).attr('id')` apparently stops being updated on a timely basis

**What I am trying to do is to conditionally "toggle droppability", reading the DOM  while hovering over an element. it appears that `accept` doesn't entirely sync with the rest of the DOM for my purposes. **

The reason is, as you will see with my example, being squares with chess pieces, depending on what square a piece is over at a particular point in time., I might not want to allow a drop.  Other times, I would want to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand this correctly, you want to toggle droppability based not only on whether or not the space is currently occupied, but also if the current move is a valid chess move (after all, some valid chess moves involve one piece taking the place of another). Is this true? If so, I would think using a complex `accept` function would, in fact, be the right strategy.

This function receives two pieces of critical information: the piece being dragged (the sole "el" argument) and the space potentially being dragged to (which is the function's `this` variable). You noted that the `accept` function is called multiple times, and this is by design: as you can see in the jQuery UI [source code](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/jquery.ui.droppable.js#L204), when a draggable is being dragged, the `accept` function will be evaluated for each droppable space on the board. This means that when you start moving a piece, each droppable space will calculate whether or not it can accept the piece.

I understand that you want to evaluate this "on the fly" as a piece passes over another square, but is the overhead of calculating it in advance causing noticeable performance issues? If not, I would go with `accept`.

**Edit:** I've created a jsFiddle that demonstrates how to use .append to move the piece from square to square: http://jsfiddle.net/58t7L/3/

**Edit by Kevin:**   Accepted because in chat Matt helped to stratify the issue to show that my method of using $(this) in accept is not exactly geared toward how accept is intended to be used. .over: would be for the process I was describing and using, while 'accept' really demands a different process, as it evaluates all droppables at once. Chat link is in comment below

Comment: Yes. good analysis.  I'm really looking to see if *accept* the *only* way to evaluate my chess rules on hover. If it is, then you win. My own experiments with *accept* are that it is clunky, and it actually doesn't always fire sometimes when you think. (and evaluation isn't causing perf. issues) That could be because I'm using it wrong, or it could be because its clunky.

Comment: I've edited the jsFiddle to console.log when "accept" is fired: http://jsfiddle.net/rUwgc/20/ ... it seems reliable to me. Are you able to create a jsFiddle where "accept" doesn't behave as expected?

There's probably a way to calculate on hover and enable/disable an acceptable parameter, but this solution seems more clunky to me... you'd end up evaluating a spot multiple times if the user hovered over it multiple times. `accept` seems like it was built for your use case.

Comment: I noticed that when acceptable is true, the `accept` function is called quite a few times (http://jsfiddle.net/rUwgc/22/). Still, if performance isn't an issue, I would think this would still be a reliable strategy.

Comment: Looking over your code again, I noticed you seem to delete/recreate the piece when it's dropped on a new square. Why not simply move the original piece?

Comment: we might want to take this into the chat room as the thread here is expanding past alternatives to accept:    http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/14543/chessmangler?tab=general

Comment: Here you go, Matt.  an example of 'accept' not firing correctly:  http://jsfiddle.net/LK9LW/2/  (I disabled drop for the example) note when you HOVER the piece between the squares rapidly, the 2 lines below will get out of sync.  Notably, the 'accept' code does not appear to fire when it needs to.  An illusion?  (also, check out chat)

Comment: actually.. you don't even need to hover the piece rapidly.. just going back to recently hovered squares will break accept.

Comment: just to be safe, I deleted all other events except for *accept* from the object that uses *accept*. still no go.  http://jsfiddle.net/UvByv/  - The event does indeed appear to fire fine, it just does not update correctly.

Comment: Later chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/14543/chessmangler?tab=general  with Matt helped to stratify the issue to show that my method of using *$(this)* in *accept* is not exactly geared toward how *accept* is intended to be used.  *.over:* would be for the process I was describing and using, while 'accept' really demands a different process, as it evaluates all droppables at once.